# Java Calc doesn't show up and exits

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have created a Java GUI based small calculator app but it is giving an issue that it is not showing anything on screen when I start it, it automatically exists immediately. What went wrong? Here is the code for my java class of SmallCalcApp: 
..........................................................................................................................................................................

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SmallCalcApp implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel firstOperand, secondOperand, answer; 
    JTextField op1, op2, ans;
    JButton plus, mul;

    public SmallCalcApp(){
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        Container con = frame.getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        plus = new JButton("+");
        mul = new JButton("*");
        con.add(plus);
        con.add(mul);


        plus.addActionListener(this);
        mul.addActionListener(this);



        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String oper, result;
            int num1, num2, res;

            if(event.getSource() == plus){
                oper = op1.getText();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                oper = op2.getText();
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                res = num1 + num2;
                result = res + "";

                ans.setText(result);
            }

            if(event.getSource() == mul){
                oper = op1.getText();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                oper = op2.getText();
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                res = num1 * num2;
                result = res + "";

                ans.setText(result);
            }
        } 


    public static void main(String args[]){
        SmallCalcApp sc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you do not create any instance of `SmallCalcApp`.

Replace:
`SmallCalcApp sc;` to `SmallCalcApp sc = new SmallCalcApp();` in order to do this.

Also, all Swing applications must run on their own thread. For more info read [this.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

So, your main should be like:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SmallCalcApp();
        });
    }
```